# How to remove the double quotes from json string except the first json value?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all

Please help me.

Here my json input.

```
{"id":"FWAX014","price":18,"quantity":1}
```

Expected output should be like this:

```
{id:"FWAX014",price:18,quantity:1}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My requirement is like that. To send the value to third party API. How to achieve this through regular expression?

Comment: you should tell the third party that they should fix their code instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex removes the double quotes you want:

```
(?<={|,)"(\w+)"
```

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/71qITz/1)

#### Explanation

- `(?<={|,)` checks that the following pattern is preceded by a curly brace or a comma
- `"(\w+)"` matches the word between the quotes

#### Example

```
$re = '/(?<={|,)"(\w+)"/';
$str = '{"id":"FWAX014","price":18,"quantity":1}';

$result = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);
```